# Proving the Kantorovich inequality

Tags: inequality, optimization

Nevermind! I worked it out. This question seems really silly now.

---

I am working through the proof of the Kantorovich inequality on pages 6 and 7 of the following lecture notes: [u.mich optimisation lecture notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mepelman/teaching/IOE511/Handouts/511notes07-7.pdf)
There's one step of it that I'm really struggling to understand. Could someone please explain to me how one gets from the RHS of the last identity on page 6 to the first LHS inequality on page 7.

I also have a little difficulty understanding the diagram. My interpretation of the diagram on page 7 is that: For any convex-hull type combination of the points $a_1, a_2,\dots , a_n,$ with weights $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n,$ we can find a $\gamma$ such that $\gamma  \frac{1}{a_1} + (1-\gamma)\frac{1}{a_n} > \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\left(\frac{1}{a_i}\right)$.

However, in the problem, aren't we simultaneously trying to ensure that for those same weights $\lambda_i$, that our $\gamma$ is also maximising $\gamma  a_1 + (1-\gamma) a_n > \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\left(\frac{1}{a_i}\right)} $, since, ultimately we're trying to find an upper bound for $\beta$ from the equation on the bottom of page 6?? How does the diagram deal with this latter aspect?

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not deface your question by erasing all its content. I reverted the question to its previous-to-last Edit.

Comment: Could you post your answer?  There may be others interested in the same question... i.e. me! :)

Answer (score 3):

This question is bugging me since, as far as I can see, the diagram illustrates
that if we define $\gamma$ by 
 $$\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i a_i =  \gamma {a_1}+(1-\gamma){a_n},$$
then 
$${1\over \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i a_i}\leq \gamma {1\over a_1}+(1-\gamma){1\over a_n},$$
which is true, but not at all useful.
We want to show that 
$$\beta=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i a_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i/a_i\right)$$
is maximized when all the weight is on $a_1$ and $a_n$. We can prove this directly using
induction, by finding a larger value of $\beta$ using fewer points.

If $n>2$, choose any $1<j<n$. Fix everything except $a_j$; all the weights $\lambda_i$ and 
all the other points $a_1, \dots, a_{j-1},a_{j+1}, \dots, a_n$. 
Let $x$ be a variable that can range freely between $a_{j-1}$ and $a_{j+1}$. 
Define $$\beta(x)=\left(\sum_{i\neq j} \lambda_i a_i+\lambda_j x\right)\left(\sum_{i\neq j} \lambda_i/a_i+\lambda_j/x\right).$$
Its second derivative is
 $$\beta^{\prime\prime}(x)=\left(\sum_{i\neq j} \lambda_i a_i\right) {2\lambda_j\over x^3}\geq 0.$$
This means that $\beta(x)$ is convex, and so its maximum occurs at one of the endpoints.
In other words, $\beta\leq\max\{\beta(a_{j-1}),\beta(a_{j+1})\}$ so we can increase $\beta$ 
by moving $a_j$ to either $a_{j-1}$ or $a_{j+1}$. This completes the induction step, and gives 
the desired result.

I expect that there is a cleverer, more direct proof but I couldn't find it.